# Detect container, while moving an element over it

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I making a simple drag'n'drop interface. I have a bunch of containers ("wrapper") and some dynamically added items ("dragElement") in one of them. So I need, when I move item over another container, JS detect it and move the item there when the drag is finished.

I tried to detect container with "onmouseover" and "mouseup" when dragging item, but had no success, because, actually, mouse always was over the dragged element.
So how can I detect container when drag item? In pure JS please...

```
document.onmousedown = function(e) {

    var dragElement = e.target;

    if (!dragElement.classList.contains('draggable')) return;

    var coords, shiftX, shiftY, detectPage;

    startDrag(e.clientX, e.clientY);

    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        moveAt(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    };

    wrapper.onmouseover = function(e) {
        detectPage = e.target;
        console.log(detectPage);
    };

    dragElement.onmouseup = function() {
        finishDrag();
    };

    function startDrag(clientX, clientY) {

        shiftX = clientX - dragElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        shiftY = clientY - dragElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        dragElement.style.position = 'fixed';

        document.body.appendChild(dragElement);

        moveAt(clientX, clientY);

    };

    function finishDrag() {

        dragElement.style.top = parseInt(dragElement.style.top) - wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px';
        dragElement.style.position = 'absolute';

        wrapper.onmouseup = function(e) {
            var selectPage = e.target;
        }

        wrapper.appendChild(dragElement);

        document.onmousemove = null;
        dragElement.onmouseup = null;

    };

    function moveAt(clientX, clientY) {
        var newX = clientX - shiftX;
        var newY = clientY - shiftY;

        if (newX < 0) newX = 0;
        if (newX > wrapper.offsetWidth - dragElement.offsetWidth) {
            newX = wrapper.offsetWidth - dragElement.offsetWidth;
        }

        dragElement.style.left = newX + 'px';
        dragElement.style.top = newY + 'px';
    };

    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one help. So one free day gone to find the solution. All I can found is to delete function `finishDrag()` from `dragElement.onmouseup` and change it to the code below.

If in shorter, when `onmouseup` comes, `dragElement` must go to `display:none` and now we can get access to the object near the mouse cursor through `elementFromPoint`. When we done with it, we can easily detects container, bring an element back to `display:block` and put it to that container...

Hope, it helps to someone...

```
    dragElement.onmouseup = function(e) {

        dragElement.style.display = 'none';

        var selectPage = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);

        dragElement.style.display = 'block';

        dragElement.style.top = parseInt(dragElement.style.top) - selectPage.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px';
        dragElement.style.position = 'absolute';

        selectPage.appendChild(dragElement);

        document.onmousemove = null;
        dragElement.onmouseup = null;

    };
```